# Store UTC in the server database and handle DST(daylight saving time)

Tags: email, utc, dst, reminders

I went through many postings related to UTC, timezone and DST. But i have a specific problem which i didn't find out any suggestion or solution to solve ....

We store an event's start time in our database after converting it to UTC, and we also want to send out an email reminder some times prior to the event start time, e.g. 30 minutes before.

Because of DST, our process of sending email reminders sometimes sent emails one hour later. I know the complexity of DST here. But there is any practice way to solve this problem. By the way, our process is a stored procedure running in MySQL. We only support time zones in Northern America.

Tony

Comment: If your times are truly stored in UTC, and you're querying in UTC, then you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: A user enters a local time and i need to use the offset based on the timezone to convert it to UTC. For a future dat, the offset might be changed due to DST. It seems to me we do have a problem here.

Comment: What language are you writing your app in?  Its date/time libraries should handle local/universal conversion for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store repeating dates keeping in mind Daylight Savings Time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626177/how-to-store-repeating-dates-keeping-in-mind-daylight-savings-time)