# What is a good practice when we need to work with datetime

Tags: database, datetime, timezone, utc, gmt

I did a travel system, so, this system has many destinations around the world, the website and mobile app of my system are multiple language.

What the better way to storage the departure time of each travel in the database?

I think that it is better to save the final datetime with its timezones.

Other approach is to convert datetime to the UTC timezone, storage it, and when my API was requested I convert the UTC to the real timezone, for example:

I select the datetime -> "10:00:00 Tuesday June 9, 2015 in America/New_York" and I convert to UTC -> "14:00:00 Tuesday June 9, 2015 in GMT+0", so I save the UTC datetime in my database.

When someone requests my api, my code will convert the UTC to America/New_York.

Comment: That's usually a sensible approach - to store dates in UTC and let clients do the heavy lifting converting into their timezone/dls time.

Comment: @defectus - That advice applies to timestamps.  It does not necessarily apply for scheduling.

Comment: @Thiago - Are you timestamping present or past event, or are you scheduling future departures?  Context matters.

Comment: @MattJohnson I am scheduling future departures

Comment: @ThiagoValentim - then you should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19627330/634824