# How to manage recurring Event for All Timezone user For Specific local Day?

Tags: date, parse-platform, timezone, parse-cloud-code, recurring-events

I am trying to develop a scheduler- and calendar-dependent event application for iOS. which use online database (parse Database) for store Event & users Detail.

Detail:

- One user Create Events for specific day (i.e. every Monday for 5 week from specific date) and invite other users in Events.
- Event will be active only on defined Days for all user i.e. if event day is Monday then event is active only on Monday for all user's Monday (local time).

Question :  how to check if event is active for user as per local time?
  desc : if event day is Friday (1/1/2016) then event is active for all user only for Friday (1/1/2016)  i.e. user local time is Friday (1/1/2016) then event is active for this user. same for all other user.

How to maintain this on Server Database and notify user to event is active for today ? 
I'm using parse database and all this logic is to be implemented on Parse using Cloud Code.

Edit : I tried to active event according to UTC timezone. For above example, event is activated at 1/1/2016 00:00:00.000Z and closes at 2/1/2016 00:00:00.000Z . This is true for user in UTC+00 but for user of UTC+5:30 event is activated at 1/1/2016 05:30:00 and close at 2/1/2016 5:30:00. But event should be active only between 1/1/2016 00:00:00 to 2/1/2016 00:00:00. Same issue for all users with different timezones.

Comment: Be sure to read [How to store repeating dates keeping in mind Daylight Savings Time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19627330/634824)

Answer (score 0):

// Try and Compare To Date This Given Below  When Change the time zone then make to  01/01/2016 00:00:00 %@ for like   UTC, GMT,etc.....

```
  NSDateFormatter *formated = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  formated.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";
  NSDate *utc = [formated dateFromString:@"01/01/2016 00:00:00 UTC"];
  formated.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
  NSString *local = [formated stringFromDate:utc];
  NSLog(@"%@", local);



  NSDateFormatter *formated2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  formated2.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";
  NSDate *utc2 = [formated2 dateFromString:@"02/01/2016 00:00:00 UTC"];
  formated2.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
  NSString *local2 = [formated2 stringFromDate:utc2];
  NSLog(@"%@", local2);
```

Comment: this will not work. You are just converting UTC time to local time.