# Time zone conversion using time zone city coordinates and local time

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone-offset, google-maps-timezone

I'm developing a scheduling web site where you can specify a date, time, time zone city. I want to save this in the backend in UTC time. So I have to convert it somehow on the server. I also want to provide the ability to convert to a different time zone on-the-fly.

In the Javascript I have a date/time value as well as a time zone city (from http://www.citytimezones.info which gives me geographical coordinates). I don't have the UTC time, only the time in the specified time zone.

Now I need to convert this future local time to UTC. Of course, it has to take into account the daylight savings time offset that will apply at that time.

Moreover I would like to convert to a different local time using a second time zone city.

I thought about using the Google Maps Time Zone API but this forces you to pass in the UTC time, which I don't have because I'm trying to calculate it.

In other words, ideally I need a system that will take these parameters:

- *Future* time/date
- Source time zone city coordinates
- Destination time zone city coordinates (or null = UTC time)

and will return the converted time.

Any idea what I could do to make this happen?

This could be either a web service or a Windows C# library.

Comment: If the time zone rule changes in the future then your future UTC time may become incorrect. And time zone rules change surprisingly often. Obviously, this problem applies to all multi timezone scheduling applications and I think the only solution is to store the original local time to be able to recalculate the UTC time if the applicable time zone rule changes in the future.

Comment: @MartinLiversage Yes, I plan to store the do that. Scheduling also saves the local time so we can recalculate the UTC time.

Comment: I don't know why this was marked as duplicate with "DateTime vs DateTimeOffset". This is so ridiculous because that other question doesn't even talk about translating between time zones. At best this could be "Google Maps Time Zone API vs DateTimeOffset" but this is stretching it.

Comment: In the end the solution was, as described by the deleted answer by +Matt Johnson, the class DateTimeOffset offers the time zone translation functionality that I was looking for. That said, I cannot undelete or vote for this answer since it's been deleted. This leaves me a bit frustrated because there's no way for me to write a proper answer to my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the problem into two parts:

- Determining the time zone from location cooridnates
- Converting time between time zones

You will find several ways to to do each.

For step 1, you mentioned Google Time Zone API, and CityTimeZones.  Both of those [are listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16086964/634824), along with several other methods.

For step 2, your choices for .NET are primarily between [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org), or `TimeZoneInfo`.  Martin gave several good examples of each [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37712994/634824).

Also, consider that *scheduling* is a more difficult scenario than most.  You should read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19627330/634824) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You need a time zone database to perform the desired date and time conversions. Time zones are more complicated than simply being an offset because many time zones include daylight savings rules.

The .NET framework allows you to use the underlying Windows time zone database by using the [`TimeZoneInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class. However, you can consider the Windows time zone database proprietary. IANA maintains the [Time Zone Database (TZDB)](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) which is described in [Best Current Practice (BCP) 175](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6557).

The library [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) has support for TZDB and provided a local timestamp as a .NET `DateTime` and a time zone identifier you can compute the corresponding UTC timestamp:

```
var localDateTime = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dateTime);
var timeZoneId = "America/New_York"];
var timeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timeZoneId];
var zonedDateTime = timeZone.AtLeniently(localDateTime);
var utcDateTime = zonedDateTime.ToDateTimeUtc();
```

Notice that the local timestamp may be ambiguous or invalid. This happens during daylight savings transitions where the local clock is moved backwards (creates ambiguity) or forward (creates invalid times). The [`AtLeniently`](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/M_NodaTime_DateTimeZone_AtLeniently.htm) method makes some assumptions about how to handle ambiguity and invalid timestamps. This may be a source of errors in your application.

When you have a UTC timestamp and a time zone ID you can convert to local time in a similar fashion:

```
var instant = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(utcDateTime);
var timeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timeZoneId];
var zonedDateTime = instant.InZone(timeZone);
var localDateTime = zonedDateTime.ToDateTimeUnspecified();
```

After taking a look at http://www.citytimezones.info/ it seems that the `cities.txt` contains the Windows time zone ID for each city in the last column. This makes it possible for you to lookup the Windows time zone ID based on the city.

You can then convert a local `DateTime` to UTC using this code:

```
var timeZoneId = "Eastern Standard Time";
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);
var utcDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(localDateTime, timeZoneInfo);
```

Notice that `ConvertTimeToUtc` will throw an `ArgumentException` if the local timestamp is ambiguous or invalid.

The reverse conversion from UTC to local time:

```
var localDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, timeZoneInfo);
```