# How can I ensure consistent datetime handling for a reservation system across different timezones?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, timezone

**The issue at a high level:**

A hotel owner sets a time range as to when a reservation can be booked at a restaurant **(5pm - 10pm)**. In this record, there will also be a timezone, so when the data gets displayed to a user, I can convert the date to the original timezone it was encoded in. This is so a user in another timezone can see the dates as they were intended and not encoded into their local timezone.

**The issue:**

If a user is in another timezone, making a reservation, their data will be stored as so:

**date: DateObj**

**timezone: zyx**

If I am now trying to retrieve all the reservations for the day, I am foreshadowing an issue:

1. If the UTC timestamp is less the previous / next day it will not be found

here is a snippet of the grabbing method

```
const startOfDay = new Date(dateParam);
startOfDay.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

const startOfNextDay = new Date(startOfDay);
startOfNextDay.setDate(startOfDay.getDate() + 1);

const reservations = await this.reservationModel
  .find({
    reservationDate: {
      $gte: startOfDay,
      $lt: startOfNextDay,
    },
    restaurantId: restaurantId,
  })
```

Potential solution:

I could pass the date as a broken up string

```
{
   day: 12,
   month:11,
   year:2024,
   time:xyz
}
```

and construct the date using the servers timezone so it will always be consistent. So when I am getting the reservations, there will be no time zoning issues since all dates will be in the servers timezone.

I was curious to know if I could set the startOfDay date variable to use the start of the UTC day. Would this be something that would work as well?

Comment: I would not want to see times in MY timezone but always in the timezone of the hotel

Comment: @mplungjan Yes that wont happen, thats why the timezone is being stored in the database as well. 5pm will be 5pm for everyone.

Comment: The issue is how? If a user in New York submits a reservation for 5pm at a hotel in LA, encoded to UTC. The reservation will be shown as 2pm @mplungjan

Comment: There are _many_ other questions about scheduling and time zones already on Stack Overflow.  I suggest you research this further before jumping to a conclusion.  The short answer is, UTC is _NOT_ desirable for scheduling future events.  You can read more in answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626177/how-to-store-repeating-dates-keeping-in-mind-daylight-savings-time/19627330#19627330) and many others.

Comment: @wowza_MAN - You store in a known time and SHOW in the local time. If you want to show the booker that they have to leave at their time to be able to arrive at the hotel time, then show both. I would certainly not want to book a hotel at date x, knowing they will let me in at 2pm and then arrive at noon, expecting to get my room immediately because I haven's set my clock to the local timezone yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't agree with @Matt  Johnson-Pint. A Date is a Date and `Date` Objects in MongoDB / JavaScript are stored as UTC time, this you cannot change. But actually you should not care about the internal storage format of a `Date` object. For example, in Oracle `DATE` are stored as internal binary value, there you don't care either.

Storing Date/Time values as string is a design flaw, you should **never** do that. This is not limited to MongoDB, it applies to any database. Here on SO you can find hundreds of question where people run into problems because they store date values wrongly as string.

Now, having said all this, regarding to your question: In general, when people have to work with times and timezones I recommend to use a 3rd party Date library, e.g. [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon), [Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/) or (deprecated) [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/). They are much easier to use.

In your case the solution could be this one:

```
const { DateTime, Settings } = require("luxon");

const reservation = DateTime.fromISO('2024-02-16T19:00:00', { zone: 'America/New_York' });
// or if you prefer
const reservation = DateTime.fromObject(
   { year: 2024, month: 11, day: 12, hour: 10, minute: 26 },
   { zone: 'America/New_York' }
)

db.reservations.insertOne({
   restaurantId: 1,
   reservationDate: reservation.toJSDate() // or your native `Date` object
})
```

If you like to get all reservations from a specific day, it could be

```
const startOfDay = DateTime.fromISO('2024-02-16', { zone: 'America/New_York' }).startOf('day');
const endOfDay = DateTime.fromISO('2024-02-16', { zone: 'America/New_York' }).endOf('day');

db.reservations.find({
   reservationDate: {
      $gte: startOfDay.toJSDate(),
      $lte: endOfDay.toJSDate(),
   },
   restaurantId: 1
})
```

All your times are in New York time zone, thus you can also use it as default:

```
Settings.defaultZone = 'America/New_York';
// Most likely it will be already set by your system settings
const reservation = DateTime.fromISO('2024-02-16T19:00:00');
// or
const reservation = DateTime.local(2024, 02, 16, 19);

const startOfDay = DateTime.fromISO('2024-02-16').startOf('day');
const endOfDay = DateTime.fromISO('2024-02-16').endOf('day');
```

will do the same.

Comment: "*Storing Date/Time values as string is a design flaw, you should never do that*. So certain are you. Consider an event at at 8:00 local on the first Monday of the month where DST is observed. The equivalent UTC time will be different depending on whether DST is being observed or not. For dates projected into the future to cover the changes, what if that place changes its DST change over rules? Or stops observing DST? Or adopts a different standard offset? All of these will confound a date stored only as UTC. So storing as a string might be preferred in some cases. Never say never. ;-)

Comment: @RobG It makes a difference whether you say "never store a date/time as string" or "store your times without time zone information" In some languages you have different timestamp data types - with and without time zone. The data type without time zone can be the better choice but in MongoDB you have no choice.

Comment: @RobG Smart libraries, for example like Luxon (but there are many more) consider this quite well. For example `DateTime.fromISO('2024-02-16T08:00') -> DateTime.fromISO('2024-02-16T08:00').plus({days: 100})` returns proper `2024-02-16T08:00:00+01:00 -> 2024-05-26T08:00:00+02:00` which is absolutely correct (I life in Switzerland). Storing date/time values as string usually meas, you try to re-invent the wheel. You should re-use what other people already did for us.