# Correct way to calculate recurring dates in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

In my project I need to calculate dates for repeating events. At the beginning I just have a start date/time and the information how this event must repeat:

```
Every Day
Every Week
Every 2 Weeks
Every 3 Weeks
Every Month
Every 2 Months
...
```

What is the right way to do this? It should work correctly with different time zones and day saving time settings. I think I should just add days/weeks/month to the local DateTime and then convert it to UTC. But I'm not sure about this. What happens if I add a few days and this will be the time when we need to adjust our clocks forward one hour. In this case this time will not exists.

Below is the code I wrote, but I'm not sure that it works correctly in every case:

```
private static List<DateTime> FindOccurrences(DateTime localStart, Repeat repeat, int occurrences)
{
    var result = new List<DateTime> { localStart };
    switch (repeat)
    {
        case Repeat.Daily:
            for (int i = 1; i <= occurrences; i++)
                result.Add(localStart.AddDays(i));
            break;
        case Repeat.Every2Weeks:
            for (int i = 1; i <= occurrences; i++)
                result.Add(localStart.AddDays((7 * 2) * i));
            break;
        ...
    }
    return result;
}

public List<Event> CreateRepeating(string timeZone, Repeat repeat, int repeatEnds, DateTime localStart, int eventDuration)
{
    var events = new List<Event>();
    var occurrences = FindOccurrences(localStart, repeat, repeatEnds);
    foreach (var occurrence in occurrences)
    {
        var item = new Event();
        item.Start = occurrence.ToUtcTime(timeZone);
        item.End = occurrence.ToUtcTime(timeZone).AddMinutes(eventDuration);
        events.Add(item);
    }
    return events;
}
```

PS:
All dates are stored in UTC format in the database.

Comment: Have a look at [NodaTime](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) - it has considered many of the challenges inherent in dates and timezones.

Answer (score 14):

Scheduling or calculating the dates of future events, especially recurring events, is a very complex subject.  I've written about this a few times, though from the perspective of other languages (See: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19170823/634824), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19627330/634824), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20828804/634824), [4](https://serverfault.com/a/554761/100701)).

I'm afraid this is too broad of a subject to give you the exact code to run.  The details will be very specific to your application.  But here are some tips.

In general:

- Use UTC only for the projected moment in time that a single instance of the event is to occur.
- Store the actual event in *local* time.  Store the time zone id also.
- Do *not* store the time zone *offset*.  That should be looked up for each occurrence individually.
- Project upcoming occurrence(s) of the event as UTC so you know how when to perform an action based on the event (or whatever makes sense for your scenario).
- Decide what to do for daylight saving time, when an occurrence falls into a spring-forward gap, or a fall-back overlap.  Your needs may vary, but a common strategy is to *jump ahead* of the spring gap, and choose the *first* occurrence in the fall.  If you're not sure what I mean, refer to [the dst tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info).
- Think carefully about how to handle dates near the end of a month.  Not all months have the same number of days, and calendar math is difficult.  `dt.AddMonths(1).AddMonths(1)` is not necessarily the same as `dt.AddMonths(2)`.
- Stay on top of time zone data updates.  Nobody can predict the future, and the governments of the world like to change things!
- You need to retain the original local-time values of the schedule, so that you can re-project the UTC values of the occurrences.  You should do this either periodically, or whenever you apply a time zone update (if you're tracking them manually).  [The timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) has details about the different time zone databases and how they are updated.
- Consider using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) and [IANA/TZDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) time zones.  They are much more suited for this type of work than the built in types and time zones Microsoft provides.
- Be careful to avoid using the local time zone.  You should have no calls to `DateTime.Now`, `ToLocalTime`, or `ToUniversalTime`.  Remember, the local time zone is based on the machine where the code is running, and that should not impact the behavior of your code.  Read more in [The Case Against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).
- If you are doing all of this to just kick off a scheduled job, you should probably take a look at a pre-canned solution, such as [Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/).  It is free, open source, highly functional, and covers a lot of edge cases you may not have thought about.

Answer (score 7):

Partial answer. I'd rather change the implementation to

```
  public enum TimePeriod {
    None = 0,
    Day = 1,
    // Just week, no "two weeks, three weeks etc."  
    Week = 2,
    Month = 3
  }

  public static class Occurrencies {
    // May be you want to convert it to method extension: "this DateTime from" 
    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> FindInterval(DateTime from,
                                                     TimePeriod period, 
                                                     int count) {
      while (true) {
        switch (period) {
          case TimePeriod.Day:
            from = from.AddDays(count); 

            break;  
          case TimePeriod.Week:
            from = from.AddDays(7 * count);    

            break;
          case TimePeriod.Month:
            from = from.AddMonths(count);    

            break;  
        } 

        yield return from;
      }
    }
  }
```

Use:

```
  // Get 5 2-week intervals 
  List<DateTime> intervals2Weeks = Occurrencies
    .FindInterval(DateTime.Now, TimePeriod.Week, 2)
    .Take(5)
    .ToList();

  // Get 11 3-month intervals 
  List<DateTime> intervals3Months = Occurrencies
    .FindInterval(DateTime.Now, TimePeriod.Month, 3)
    .Take(11)
    .ToList();
```