# Should a time within the end of DST hour be considered Winter or Summer time?

Tags: datetime, timezone, dst

As we know, when ever our clocks go 1h back (as they did on 29OCT at 2:00 in some countries) ending the DST period, every timestamp between 1:00 and 2:00 'occurs' twice.

How should an application working with future events handle this?

For example user creates a future event and specifies that it will take a place on 29OCT at 1:35. 
And let's assume that standard local time is UTC+3 and the DST is UTC+4

How should the application convert this time to UTC? Should this time be considered as the first instance (before end of DST, which makes it 21:35 UTC) or the second instance (after end of DST, i.e. 22:35 UTC)?

Answer (score 1):

Only you can decide that.  It is largely based on context.

In many cases, the right thing to do is to choose the *first* of the two occurrences - which would be the *daylight* time.  In your example, it would run at 1:35 in UTC+4.

You also need to consider the spring-forward transition.  A recurring task that falls into the gap should *usually* be displaced by an amount equal to the DST bias (which is usually 1 hour).  For example, if the clock jumps from 1:59:59.999 to 3:00, then a task scheduled to run at 2:30 would run at 3:30 on that day.

Again, only you can decide what is the right behavior for your application.  Some applications may need the fall event to run at the standard time, or at *both* times.  In the spring, they may want to run at the very next instant past the gap (3:00 in the above example, instead of 3:30) - or they may not want to run at all.

See also:

- [The DST Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info)
- [How to store repeating dates keeping in mind Daylight Savings Time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19627330/634824)
- [Correct way to calculate recurring dates in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26368158/634824)
- [java Calendar, Date, and Time management for a multi-timezone application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19170823/634824)
- [Scheduled Jobs during hours of autumn time change](https://serverfault.com/a/554761/100701)

Comment: Excellent response.  Do you know how the java Calendar class treats the ambiguous time values on the days that DST changes?   e.g. Calendar.set(year,month,day,hour,minute,second).    Is there an easy way to test for whether a particular hour on a given day is ambiguous or missing?

Comment: I know that Java 8 `java.time` package does indeed have the behavior I described in the first two paragraphs.  I'm not sure about older java.  It's fairly easy to try and see what happens. ;)