# Update android time zone data

Tags: android, timezone, kernel, android-4.4-kitkat, icu

I am running **Android 4.4.3** on my device and of course it has outdated time zones and I am trying to update the **tzdata in /system/usr/share/zoneinfo**. However replacing the file straight away does not update the time zone.

Since **ICU** keeps its own copy of the time zone data we have to replace that as well (according to Google AOSP team) . The updated data files are [Update for ICU](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/111773/) and [Update for bionic](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/111669/)

However, I when I build and replace the the **icu4c libraries (libicui18n.so and libicuuc.so) and replace icudt51l.dat with icudt53l.dat**, the system cannot initialize ICU.

I have tried unpacking the icudt53l.dat and pushing its *.res files inside old icudt51l.dat but that failed as well because ICUPKG tool checks the checksum of the res file before packing them.

I followed [XDA link to update tzdata](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1324935) but that approach failed because they create **zoneinfo.dat, zoneinfo.idx, zoneinfo.version** files using tzdata. But the system looks for **tzdata itself in /system/usr/share/zoneinfo**

I am not a time zone or ICU expert, could you please point me if am looking in the wrong direction and help.

Comment: Are you asking about updating the os, icu, or both?

Comment: I want to update the icu only, but if any other components of the OS are dependent on the ICU version, I don't mind updating the OS.

Comment: Does [Updating the Time Zone Data](http://userguide.icu-project.org/datetime/timezone#TOC-Updating-the-Time-Zone-Data) from the ICU user guide answer your question?

Comment: I tried packaging the **metaZones.res, timezoneTypes.res, windowZones.res and zoneinfo64.res** nto the current icudt51l.dat I have on my device. Also changed the corresponding tzdata but still no effect.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583662/how-to-handle-jodatimes-and-androids-timezone-database-differences

Comment: FWIW - I'd like to see a definitive answer as well.  I'd answer, but I'm not familiar enough with the specific implementation details within Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not necessary to update ICU or Bionic, you can simply change the `tzdata` file with the updated one.  Also you don't need to manually generate the file `tzdata` from the IANA time zone data. You can take the already builded `tzdata` from the [bionic repo](https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/). You can find the update file to the last version of Time Zone Data v. 2015g [here](https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/zoneinfo/tzdata?raw=true).

Once you download the file copy it on your device (e.g. `/sdcard/Download/tzdata`), then open a shell:

```
shell@maguro:/ $ su
shell@maguro:/ $ setprop persist.sys.timezone Europe/Istanbul
shell@maguro:/ $ date -s 20151106.130000
Fri Nov  6 13:00:00 EET 2015
root@maguro:/ # mount -o rw,remount /system
root@maguro:/ # cd /system/usr/share/zoneinfo/
root@maguro:/system/usr/share/zoneinfo # cp tzdata tzdata.bak
root@maguro:/system/usr/share/zoneinfo # cp /sdcard/Download/tzdata tzdata
root@maguro:/system/usr/share/zoneinfo # chmod 644 tzdata
root@maguro:/system/usr/share/zoneinfo # date
Fri Nov  6 14:00:47 EEST 2015
```

If after this it still doesn't work:

```
root@maguro:/ # cd /data/misc/zoneinfo/
root@maguro:/data/misc/zoneinfo # cp tzdata tzdata.bak
root@maguro:/data/misc/zoneinfo # cp /sdcard/Download/tzdata tzdata
root@maguro:/data/misc/zoneinfo # chmod 644 tzdata
```

As you can see with the updated `tzdata` the time zone of Europe/Istanbul on 6th November changes from `EET` to `EEST` because in v. 2015g the Turkey's DST fall-back moving from the 25th October to 8th November.

Comment: +1 I already replaced the tzdata a dozen times but never did the date command from adb. I noticed date moved back 1 hour for Moscow which is correct. However, Settings app still showed GMT+4 rather than GMT+3. I deleted dalvik-cache and now it shows GMT+3, never thought about this earlier. Do you know which system calls depend on the ICU though?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a list of system calls that depend on the ICU. I tried to make a quick search in the JAVA part of android repo and the only reference to ICU's timezone seems `TimeZoneNames` in [ZoneGetter.java](https://goo.gl/gkgOjv). In other places instead it uses directly the `tzdata` file, for example in [ZoneInfoDB.java](https://goo.gl/KL5qlF)