# Query with momentjs

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have a problem with momentjs, when I type datetime today, it's work fine, but I type date in august (my country change the time zone) I see the datetime wrong because I'm not in this time zone at this moment.

I Don't understand to fix it.

Comment: This a problem with dates in programming in general, i'm working on an app now at work where dates are very important i will send you some resources

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices
http://www.creativedeletion.com/2015/03/19/persisting_future_datetimes.html 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166995/java-calendar-date-and-time-management-for-a-multi-timezone-application/19170823#19170823 
https://www.w3.org/TR/timezone/#pastfuture 
https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/440

Comment: You should remove the offset if you're not in DST and the time set is then check to see if the date is what you expect without offset if not then it was set in the deadzone and you should notify the user that the time set doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks @JoeWarner for your help.

Comment: No worries the more you research into dates the more your head hurts 