# Display and manipulate datetimes in JavaScript without local time zone

Tags: javascript, timezone, timezone-offset

I have a system with users spread all over the world and assigned to a couple of geographic organizational units - basically, each unit has a time zone assigned, usually one that matches the time zone for unit's HQ location. To handle different time zones everything is  done using UTC dates and times in both, backend and front-end.

At the moment I'm looking to refactor the front end to show and manipulate datetimes using the local time zone of the unit. A lot of the users are working remote or have access to multiple units so the time zone of their system might not match the unit time zone.

So the basic question here is what is the proper way to store and manipulate the date times  in front-end to be able to save the data back in database as UTC and then read it back and displayed as the local time of the unit.

I played a little bit with JS libraries like Luxon or Moment Timezone and it seems they can do the job but I was wondering if it can be done using only the browser's API like Date object or Intl namespace object.

I read a lot of posts on StackOverflow that tackle creating a date time in a different time zone but I didn't find an accepted solution for a problem like mine. In pseudo-code my problem will resume to this:

```
/**
 * @param string sessionStartTime (represents the UTC date formatted as ISO string (eg. 2022-04-27T05:06:07.000)
 * @param string timezone (eg. America/Los_Angeles)
 * @param integer minutesToAdd (eg. 45)
 */
function getSessionEndDateTime(sessionStartTime, timezone, minutesToAdd) {
    // Some processing - create a new Date object, add minutes, format the output
    return localDateTimeFormatted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Outputting** times in a given time zone can be achieved with standard browser functions: Perform the time arithmetic (adding xx minutes) in UTC and then convert the result into the desired time zone:

```
function getSessionEndDateTime(sessionStartTime, timezone, minutesToAdd) {
  var result = new Date(sessionStartTime);
  result.setUTCMinutes(result.getUTCMinutes() + minutesToAdd);
  return Intl.DateTimeFormat("en", {
    timeZone: timezone,
    ... other formatting options ...
  }).format(result);
}
var midnightUTC = new Date("2023-04-28");
getSessionEndDateTime(midnightUTC, "America/Los_Angeles", 45);
```

The format can be controlled through the [other formatting options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat). For maximum control, you can use the following options

```
day: "numeric",
month: "numeric",
year: "numeric",
hour12: false,
hour: "numeric",
minute: "numeric",
second: "numeric"
```

and replace `.format(result)` with `.formatToParts(result)`. This gives you

```
[
  { type: 'month', value: '4' },
  { type: 'literal', value: '/' },
  { type: 'day', value: '27' },
  { type: 'literal', value: '/' },
  { type: 'year', value: '2023' },
  { type: 'literal', value: ', ' },
  { type: 'hour', value: '17' },
  { type: 'literal', value: ':' },
  { type: 'minute', value: '45' },
  { type: 'literal', value: ':' },
  { type: 'second', value: '00' }
]
```

which you can recombine on your UI as you see fit.

What's not possible so easily is **inputting** a time that a user enters in a given time zone and storing it in UTC in the backend. Browsers can parse times in the *browser time zone*, as demonstrated by the snippet below, but this would not work for your *unit time zone*, which you said can differ from the browser time zone. For parsing times in an arbitrary time zone, use a date/time library<sup>1</sup>.

```js
function time(value) {
  document.querySelector('#L').textContent = value;
  document.querySelector('#U').textContent = new Date(value).toISOString();
}
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" onchange="time(this.value)" /><br>
Local time: <span id="L"></span><br>
UTC time: <span id="U"></span>
```

<sup>1</sup> I made a crude alternative attempt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76002965/16462950).